# Target cells in a Pivot Table

Tags: knockout.js

Is there an easy way to target the cells in the pivot table structure below so the values apear in the corresponding cells? (Mind that an update to the dataset array should be reflected automatically) I think I just need a dynamic-row-to-cell binding method - is it even possible in knockout.js?

I have a pivot table template like this:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>pivot</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>d</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>e</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>f</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>g</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>i</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

and the following data (defined as observable in knockout.js) I would like to display in the grid:

```js
var dataset = [
        {x: 'a', y: 1, val: 'val_1'},
        {x: 'a', y: 1, val: 'val_2'},
        {x: 'a', y: 1, val: 'val_3'},
        {x: 'a', y: 2, val: 'val_4'},
        {x: 'a', y: 2, val: 'val_5'},
        {x: 'a', y: 2, val: 'val_6'},
        {x: 'a', y: 3, val: 'val_7'},
        {x: 'a', y: 4, val: 'val_8'},
        {x: 'a', y: 4, val: 'val_9'},
        {x: 'a', y: 5, val: 'val_10'},
    ];
```

I would like to know if it's possible to bind to an existing html structure since the knockout.js seems to be a 'DOM-generator' framework when working with collections.

Comment: The post reads a bit more like a to-do than as a question. There are many different ways to do this. Have a go at this yourself and get back to us if you have a *specific* question.

Comment: You will want a custom binding handler. This one may actually do what you want (or maybe not quite). https://github.com/mbest/knockout-table

Comment: Every knockout.js example generates the DOM depending on the model, I would like to display and observe my model on an existing html structure. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible but will involve some development - two loops for X and Y columns(unique values for each) and value where the intersection is. The result is pretty nice for a dynamic html but the whole solution starts to run sluggish after more than a couple of thousand elemnts in JSON array are processed.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jeroen says, it's not difficult to conceive a solution to this problem which is somehow Knockout-bound. However, Knockout's advantage lies in being an MVVM provider whereas your example markup doesn't offer any possibility for two-way binding because of a lack of <input/> elements.

I actually went to the bother of putting together an example which would render your dataset in the table but which ultimately required knowledge of the DOM's structure from inside the view-model.

There are two considerations here:

1. Assuming that you don't need two-way binding and are happy to use a function which has knowledge of the DOM - perhaps calling this function from inside a view-model - then I could provide a simple solution. *But...* This isn't recommended because one of the principles of MVVM is that your view-model *doesn't* have this knowledge.
2. If you *do* want two-way binding via Knockout then you have to bear in mind that your dataset could theoretically have any number of objects, referring to any number of table rows and cells. Now, given that Knockout binds view-models to model-views based upon `data-bind` attributes, you'd have to dynamically add these, then re-bind each time the dataset mutated - this re-binding would negate any advantage offered by Knockout. You'd also have to remove all existing `data-bind` attributes from the table first.

So sure, there are messy ways to achieve it. And if you're willing to forego two-way binding then there are ways to do it without Knockout.

I'm afraid I can't see this being achievable *and* practical.

One possible avenue of investigation: I believe Ryan Niemeyer has a Knockout plugin which performs the data-binding without using `data-bind` attributes and is more unobtrusive.

Comment: This is not what I'm asking about. I would like to know if it's possible to bind to an existing html structure since the knockout.js seems to be a 'DOM-generator' framework when working with the collections.

Comment: Yes, you can bind to existing HTML. Knockout will only _add_ DOM elements if you use either `template`, `component` or `foreach` bindings - and even then, it's arguably only the `foreach` binding which will add more elements.